# Simulate from a distribution function using Rejection Method

Tags: r, simulation, probability-density

I am trying to simulate data 10000 observations for the following distribution:

```
         { 3x(1-x)2         0 < x < 1

  f(x) = { 3(2-x)(1-x)2     1 ≤ x  < 2

         { 0                otherwise
```

Using the rejection method, I am boxing the distribution by the following rectangle:  `x=0,x=2,y=0,y=2`

However, there is some fault in my code below as it doesn't seem to work. Can any one please advise on a fix?

```
n=10000
t=0
x=0
while(t<n)
    {u=runif(1,0,2)
    y=runif(1,0,2) 
    if {(u in c(0:1))
        fun=3*u*(1-u)^2
    else (u in c(1:2))
        fun=3*(2-u)*(1-u)^2}
    if (y<fun)
      {t=t+1
      x[t]=u}}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: I get the following error in R:
Error: unexpected '{' in:
"y=runif(1,0,2) 
if {"
> fun=3*u*(1-u)^2
Error: object 'u' not found
> else (u in c(1:2))
Error: unexpected 'else' in "else"
> fun=3*(2-u)*(1-u)^2}
Error: unexpected '}' in "fun=3*(2-u)*(1-u)^2}"
> if (y<fun)
+ {t=t+1
+ x[t]=u}}
Error: unexpected '}' in:
"{t=t+1
x[t]=u}}"

Comment: Just to add - if I remove the unexpected "{" .. then R just hangs and does not run the simulation.
My concern is that it might be on an infinite loop and once I break the operation, I receive the following statement in the console window:
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
Would appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bunch of R syntax errors. You should review a basic R introduction. be careful with placement of braces. Also there is no `in` keyword in R.

```
n <- 10000
t <- 0
x <- 0
while(t<n) {
 u <- runif(1,0,2)
 y <- runif(1,0,2) 
 if (u > 0 & u < 1) {
  fun <- 3*u*(1-u)^2
 } else if (u >= 1 & u < 2) {
  fun <- 3*(2-u)*(1-u)^2
 } else {
  fun <- 0
 }
 if (y<fun){
   t <- t+1
   x[t] <- u
 }
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated mate.